# MySQL select random 1 image per group 1 SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, select, random

I want to show random images in 4 divs.

In div 1: 1 random image with div_id 0.
In div 2: 1 random image with div_id 1.
In div 3: 1 random image with div_id 2.
In div 4: 1 random image with div_id 3.

My simplified table:

```
id_img     id_div
  1          0
  2          0
  3          0
  4          1
  5          1
  6          2
  7          2
  8          3
  9          3
 10          3
```

For example the result can be:

```
id_img     id_div
  2          0
  4          1
  7          2
 10          3
```

and the next time the result might be:

```
id_img     id_div
  3          0
  5          1
  6          2
  8          3
```

I think it's possible with only one SELECT, I tried several queries like this one:

```
SELECT id_div , id_img 
FROM img_table
WHERE id_div in ('0' ,'1' , '2' , '3')
GROUP BY id_div 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY RAND()
```

But unfortunately I don't get the result what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution just uses one `group by` with the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
SELECT id_div,
       substring_index(group_concat(id_img order by rand()), ',', 1) as id_img
FROM img_table
WHERE id_div in ('0', '1' , '2', '3')
GROUP BY id_div 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Nice solution. Prefer it to mine.

Comment: It works fine except a new problem. I had to change in the database column type from int to varchar. So I can't use the auto increment option anymore.

Comment: You should still be able to use an INT field (even if it somewhat abuses MySQL to use GROUP_CONCAT on integers it is something that I have done). If necessary you can CAST id_img to a character inside the GROUP_CONCAT. Problem comes if you want to use this query as a sub query and join to a table based on id_img (which would force type conversions and slow things down).

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to auto incrementing values.  But you can convert it back to an int with an explicit `cast()` or by adding `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery approach with order by rand() in order to get random one image per each div

```
SELECT i.id_div ,
(SELECT id_img FROM img_table WHERE id_div=i.id_div ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS id_img 
FROM img_table i
WHERE i.id_div in ('0' ,'1' , '2' , '3')
GROUP BY i.id_div 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0dcd/5)

Comment: Snap! Pretty much the same solution entered at the same second.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.

Crude solution would be a correlated sub query to bring back a random image for an id_div:-

```
SELECT id_div , 
    (SELECT id_img
        FROM img_table t
        WHERE t.id_div = main.id_div
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1) AS id_img
FROM img_table main
WHERE id_div in ('0' ,'1' , '2' , '3')
GROUP BY id_div 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This isn't likely to be quick (order by RAND() isn't quick, and correlated sub queries are also not quick).

[SQL fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2345b/2)

Comment: Exactly, when I search for this I find only solutions with sub queries.